# What could be causing "invalid hook call" errors when upgrading from React v18.2 to v18.3?

Tags: reactjs

I was on the latest stable React (18.2), but decided to try the canary channel (18.3) as recommended by the docs, to check if my app is doing anything that will error in the next React update. So I updated both `react` and `react-dom` to use the `canary` channel.

With React 18.3 (canary) my app doesn't render at all, and the console has a bunch of "Invalid hook call" errors. There are several warnings but then it says "The above error occurred in the `<Provider>` component" (which is from `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'`).

I understand the rules of hooks, and I've verified I'm following every rule on the [Invalid hook call warning](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) docs page. Indeed, the app works perfectly on React 18.2. From the error messages, it sounds like the issue might be in how `react-redux` uses hooks.

So **what has changed between React 18.2 and React 18.3 that could possibly cause my (or react-redux's) hook calls to suddenly be invalid?** Unfortunately there is nothing about the canary channel on the [Invalid hook call warning](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) docs page.

Comment: What version of Redux are you on? There was a reported issue for wrappers + styledcomponents which required an upstream fix: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21848
Wondering if it's the same for Redux.

Comment: I’m on the latest stable version of everything (except react and react-dom). If redux needed fixing to be compatible with the upcoming React 18.3 release then I’d be very surprised if this hadn’t been noticed and fixed already as these libraries go hand in hand for so many people